# Installing WALA

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I really want to use the Static Java Slicer that is implemented by WALA. But Unfortunately I've been really struggling to get started with it. This is what I've done:

- First, I downloaded Eclipse 4.2 (64 bit version)
- Then I used git clone to obtain "WALA" files
- I downloaded dx.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddxjar.htm
- I went into "com.ibm.wala.dalvik.test" and created a folder named "lib"
- I put dx.jar into "lib".
- I went into the root directory (the directory that contains all of the wala projects e.g. com.ibm.wala.cast), using windows command processor (cmd)
- I typed "mvn clean verify -DskipTests=true -q"

And I get the following error message:

[image]

I tried to import the project into eclipse anyway (using the import existing projects option), and all of the project have errors. I'm using jre1.8.0_65 and my compiler compliance level set to 1.7.

Does anyone know where I've gone wrong? Could you please help?

Comment: Well it says it can't find `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx`. Are you running on a Mac? Are you using a version of Eclipse that includes the Java (JDT) tools?

Comment: I am using a windows computer. I'm not sure, the userguide said it recommends using eclipse 4.2. I assume this would be included?

Comment: Well it is looking for the macosx launching code which won't be in the Windows download.

Comment: Thank you very much. The userguide "http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/UserGuide:Getting_Started" seems to imply that the software will work for windows. Do you have any advice for how to obtain the maven build "mvn clean verify -DskipTests=true -q" for windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the line from **com.ibm.wala.ide.jdt.test\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF**

```
org.eclipse.jdt.launching.macosx;resolution:=optional,
```

And do not download WALA as github zip archive it will throw another error:

```
One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called
```

More details:

- https://github.com/wala/WALA/issues/94
- https://sourceforge.net/p/wala/mailman/wala-wala/?viewmonth=201408